# Is it good practice to create a factory implementation which uses other factories to build the final concrete object?

Tags: php, design-patterns, dependency-injection, factory

In an application I'm building there's a CLI entry point class:

```
class CLIEntryPoint {

   protected $factory;

   public function __construct(ApplicationObjectFactoryInterface $factory) {
      $this->factory = $factory;
   }

   public function run(...$args) {
      $choice = $args[1];
      $appObject = $this->factory->makeApplicationObject($choice);
      $appObject->doApplicationRelatedStuff();
   }
}
```

This entry point is created using Dependency Injection in my "front controller" script and it receives an `ApplicationObjectFactoryInterface` implementation (actually the current implementation of `ApplicationObjectFactoryInterface` is injected by the DI container, which in turn reads it from its configuration file, but that's not the point).

The current implementation of `ApplicationObjectFactoryInterface` also uses DI and depends on other factories which help it building the resulting application object:

```
class CurrentImplementationOfApplicationObjectFactory implements ApplicationObjectFactoryInterface {

   protected $someComponentFactory;
   protected $anotherComponentFactory;

   public function __construct(SomeComponentFactoryInterface $someComponentFactory, AnotherComponentFactoryInterface $anotherComponentFactory) {
      $this->someComponentFactory = $someComponentFactory;
      $this->anotherComponentFactory = $anotherComponentFactory;
   }

   /**
   * Interface's method
   * 
   * @return ApplicationObjectInterface
   */
   public function makeApplicationObject($choice) {
      $component = $this->someComponentFactory->makeSomeComponent();
      $anotherComponent = $this->anotherComponent->makeAnotherComponent();
      switch ($choice) {
         case 1:
            return new CurrentImplementationOfApplicationObject1($component, $anotherComponent);
         case 2:
            return new CurrentImplementationOfApplicationObject2($component, $anotherComponent);
         default:
            return new DefaultImplementationOfApplicationObject($component, $anotherComponent);
      }
   }

}
```

Here `CurrentImplementationOfApplicationObject1`, `CurrentImplementationOfApplicationObject2` and `DefaultImplementationOfApplicationObject` all implement the `ApplicationObjectInterface` interface and therefore they all have the `doApplicationRelatedStuff` method.

I would like to know whether it's good practice or not to write code like I did and if not how can I improve it.

Basically here I am creating a component which depends on other components in order to function properly using a factory which in turn needs inner factories to build the component which implements the `ApplicationObjectInterface` interface.

Is it considered good practice?

Thanks for the attention, as always!

EDIT: I looked at the article of Steven and tried to refactor CLIEntryPoint. The only problem now seems to be how to pass the `$choice` parameter to the factory which now is inside of the proxy when the `run()` method is called. Is this code structure better than the one I posted above? Of course, `SomeComponentFactoryInterface` and `AnotherComponentFactoryInterface` should follow the same behaviour (the factory that uses them should not use them directly, but through two proxies which implement, in order, `SomeComponentInterface` and `AnotherComponentInterface`). I hope I get it right, anyway, here is the code:

```
class CLIEntryPoint {

   protected $applicationObject;

   public function __construct(ApplicationObjectInterface $applicationObject) {
      $this->applicationObject = $applicationObject;
   }

   public function run(...$args) {
      $choice = $args[1]; // How do I deal with different choices when I am using a Proxy? I should have different application objects depending on input.
      $this->applicationObject->doApplicationRelatedStuff();
   }
}

interface ApplicationObjectInterface {

    public function doApplicationRelatedStuff();

}

class ApplicationObjectProxy implements ApplicationObjectInterface {

    protected $applicationObjectFactory;
    protected $applicationObjectImplementation = NULL;

    public function __construct(ApplicationObjectFactoryInterface $factory) {
        $this->applicationObjectFactory = $factory;
    }

    public function __call($method, $args) {
        // Calling interface's
        $implementation = $this->getImplementation();
        $methodOfInterfaceToCall = preg_replace('/Proxy$/', '', $method);
        return $implementation->{$methodOfInterfaceToCall}(...$args);
    }

    /**
     * Laxy loading method.
     */
    protected function getImplementation() {
        if (is_null($this->applicationObjectImplementation)) {
            $this->applicationObjectImplementation = $this->applicationObjectFactory->makeApplicationObject(); // Choice should go here somehow...
        }
        return $this->applicationObjectImplementation;
    }

    public function doApplicationRelatedStuff() {
        // This will call the PHP's magic `__call` method, which in turn will forward the call to the application object's
        // implementation returned by the factory.
        return $this->doApplicationRelatedStuffProxy();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should read [this](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100).

Comment: Thank you for insight! I hope I get it right. Please check my edit. I tried to refactor my code so that `CLIEntryPoint` now depends on the interface of the application object. Then there's an implementation which acts as a proxy and forwards its calls to the calls made to the actual implementation, which I get from an inner factory which now is internal to the proxy and thus not a dependency of `CLIEntryPoint`. My problem now is with the initial `$choice` parameter, which I don't now how to pass to the factory as I have moved it inside of the proxy... Could you please comment my code?

Answer (score 1):

Actually yes, this is a pattern called the **Abstract Factory Pattern**.  So an example that I used to present it in front of my class during my undergrad:

So if you are building a video game first person shooter, you might want to create three concrete factories like:

1. FlyingMonsterFactory
2. SwimmingMonsterFactory
3. WalkingMonsterFactory.

All these factories would implement an abstract MonsterFactory.

With this, you can have your video game create a level in which you want waves of the same type of monsters, so you can have a randomWaveMonsterGenerator method return a MonsterFactory which might have returned a concrete SwimmingMonsterFactory.  So then you will have a wave of SwimmingMonster(s) generated by the SwimmingMonsterFactory.

---

**So answer your description more directly**, looking at your code above, you asked the question on choice for **Dependency Injection**.  With **Dependency Injection**, I believe for this type of pattern, you will have to inject every concrete class before your code even attempts to get the implementation class.

So for example:

- Your code above says the run method gives an argument called
  **choice**.
- With this **choice**, you will have to use it as a parameter into a **getImplementation** method.
- All the concrete objects that the getImplementation method that rely upon **Dependency
  Injection** have to be created BEFORE you call the **getImplementation** method.
- But since you don't know which implementation class will be called, I believe you have to inject ALL the implementation classes before hand.
- Then you can use the **choice** variable as a parameter to get the correct implemented factory class.

Hope this helps!